# How to do a htaccess rewrite with a question mark ? in the original url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got to redirect a URL that has a question mark in it, and I just can't figure out the proper .htaccess code to make it happen.

Example:
redirect 301 /home.php?cat=16 http://www.example.com/furniture.html

I believe I need to do a rewrite condition, but I'm no htaccess expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [`Redirect` directive from mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) you can only examine the [URI path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) and not the query (applies to all [directives of mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)). If you want to examine the URI query you need to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=16$
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://www.example.com/furniture.html? [L,R=301]
```

The empty query in the replacement will prevent that the original query is being appended to the new URI.

Answer (score 1):

From the [apache2 `mod_rewrite` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **What is matched?**
>
> The Pattern will initially be matched
>   against the part of the URL after the
>   hostname and port, and before the
>   query string. If you wish to match
>   against the hostname, port, or query
>   string, use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the
>   `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or
>   `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables
>   respectively.

Answer (score 0):

for more complex parameters (like **site.com/index.php?blaa=1&id=33** )

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} blaa=1&id=33
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/yourpage.html? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```